# react-router-dom(^5.3.0) -> redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

use Chrome to access ULR :   '/home/page1' .  (visit '/home' can turn to '/home/page1')

This can't render `<Page1>`

```
      <Switch>
        <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/page1" />
        <Route path="/home/page1">
          <Page1 />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

following two methods can  render Page1. i want to know WHY!

- 1 put it behind

```
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home/page1">
          <Page1 />
        </Route>
        <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/page1" />
      </Switch>
```

- 2 add to ‘exact’ props

```
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/home" to="/home/page1" />
        <Route path="/home/page1">
          <Page1 />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

Comment: use Chrome to access ULR :   '/home/page1'  .    visit '/home' can

Answer (score 3):

Within the `Switch` component path order and specificity matter! You should order the paths from more specific to less specific. This gives the `Switch` the opportunity to match the more specific paths first, falling back to less specific paths.

### Why it doesn't work

`"/home"` is a path prefix to `"/home/page1"` and matches both. The following code creates a loop where the path you redirect to also matches the path you are redirecting from. In other words, you are basically redirecting from `"/home/page1"` to `"/home/page1"` since `"/home/page1"` is still matched by `"/home"`.

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/page1" />
  <Route path="/home/page1">
    <Page1 />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

### Version 1

`"/home/page1"` is more specific than `"/home"` allowing it to be matched and rendered before the redirect. `"/home"` doesn't match `"/home/page1"` and so the first route is skipped. Later the redirect ***is*** matched and rendered.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/home/page1">
    <Page1 />
  </Route>
  <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/page1" />
</Switch>
```

### Version 2

Works because the less specific `"/home"` path must ***exactly*** match in order to be matched and rendered. `"/home/page1"` doesn't ***exactly*** match and so the redirect is skipped. Later the route with `path="/home/page1"` ***is*** matched and rendered.

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect exact from="/home" to="/home/page1" />
  <Route path="/home/page1">
    <Page1 />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: thank you     i know  actually  in <Redirect>   the props  "from " also match。 in th end  <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/page1" />  become <Redirect from="/home/page1" to="/home/page1" />  .  looping  so can't render <Page1>

Comment: @王逍遥 Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are getting at in your comment.

Comment: @王逍遥 Do you have further question/issue that my answer hasn't addressed or resolved, or has my answer sufficiently addressed your concerns?

Comment: yes ！ your answer help me to know <Redirect> deeply. very grateful. @Drew Reese